# How I can change the position of the figcaption under the image in large screens to the right side of an image in mobile?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive

I want to pass the caption from the bottom of the image to the right side like I show in the next images. I need the caption under the image when it is in laptop or tablet, but in the right side when the website change to mobile phone. I tried the flex with media queries but nothing change.

I don't know if it is possible do this 'cause I don't find any in my search.

How can I pass from this:

[image: Version in large screens, with caption under the images/icons]

To this:

[image: Version in Mobile, with caption on the right side of the images/icons]

My code is:

```css
.content {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 100vh;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left:10%;
}

 figcaption {
        
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
        
    }

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 180px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    
    .content{
        height: 50vh;  
        
    margin-top:25vh;
    margin-bottom: 25vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
    
    .content img{
        
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    figcaption {
        
        width: 70%;
        color:aquamarine;
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/01.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>300m<sup>2</sup></figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 space">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/02.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>4</figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 space">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/03.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>6</figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 space">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/04.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>300m<sup>2</sup></figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and I don't know what I can change.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to the figure element, and get the default `flex-direction: row;`.

```css
.content {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 100vh;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left:10%;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
}

 figcaption {
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   align-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 900;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;    
 }

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 180px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    
    .content{
        height: 50vh;  
        
    margin-top:25vh;
    margin-bottom: 25vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
    
    .content img{
        
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    figcaption {
        
        width: 70%;
        color:aquamarine;
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/01.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>300m<sup>2</sup></figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 space">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/02.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>4</figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 space">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/03.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>6</figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 space">
         <figure>
            <img src='imgs/04.png' alt='missing' />
            <figcaption>300m<sup>2</sup></figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) should do the work.
To make float work right, you need to have non-inline elements, with defined width.

```
figure > * {
    float : left;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}
```